# show only certain rows with top

Tags: mac, terminal, geektool

Using Geektool I want to output some of the stats that `top` spits out on my desktop, but not all of them.  Rather than calling `top | grep "Line_I_want_to_spit_out"` for each different line I want it to show(resulting in 5-6 separate calls to top), is it possible to just call top once and select the lines I want it to show? (ex. show Processes, CPU usage, PhysMem, and the top 10 processes ordered by cpu)

Comment: Which lines do you want to display?

Comment: Processes, CPU usage, PhysMem, Networks and 10 processes ordered by cpu usage

Comment: On the command line, `top | grep PATTERN` keeps refreshing, rather than just producing a single static output. Is this what you want? (I'm not familiar with Geektool.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not averse to using grep, you can do something like `top | grep -E "Line1|Line2|etc"`

Comment: That definitely works for the information on top.  Do you know if it's possible to also have it show the top 10 processes ordered by cpu usage (top -n10 -o-CPU -stats cpu,command)? Or would that have to be a second call to top?

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
ps -arcwwwxo "command %cpu %mem" | grep -v grep | head -9
```

Comment: While this might answer the question it might be good to break out and explain the separate parts to educate as well as answer the question.